# Adding a unit to calc

Tags: css, less, css-calc

When using calc, how can you add a unit?

I have tried the following:

```
font-size: calc(((768 / 100) * 6) / 16)rem;

font-size: calc(((768 / 100) * 6) / 16) rem;

font-size: calc(((768 / 100) * 6) / 16) + rem;

font-size: unit(calc(((768 / 100) * 6) / 16), rem);
```

I am using a LESS compiler, but can't find any indication on how in the LESS docs.

**Edit** - I have also tried removing 'calc':

```
font-size: ((768 / 100) * 6) / 16 rem
```

This outputs: `font-size: 2.88 rem`

How can you join 'rem' with the number?

Comment: A space between the number and the unit is ignored. `2.88 rem` is treated the same as `2.88rem`

Comment: simply like this: `font-size: calc(((768 / 100) * 6rem) / 16);` ? or `font-size: calc((((768 / 100) * 6) / 16) * 1rem);` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can in less use like this code

```
font-size: ((768 / 100) * 6) / 16rem;
```

in compile you can get this CSS

```
 font-size:2.88rem;
```